# Responding inline to ordered lists

Tags: gmail

I often receive emails with ordered lists, and I want to respond line-by-line.  If my responses are short enough, I can just do this:

> 1. something // my response goes here
> 2. something else // my response goes here

and so on.  However, if I have a long (paragraph-sized) response to an item, I want to start it on its own line.  But of course, Gmail then renumbers the remaining items, so I end up with something like this:

> 1. something
>
> [A verbose response here]
>
> 1. something else
>
> [something overly wordy here]

See how they are both now numbered "1" ?  Usually I end up reformatting the email I'm replying to (switching the list to a bulleted list or something).

Do you have a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a previously made list within the *quoted* section, it is tricky if not impossible. The time taken in making it work, if it is even possible is much greater than just copying the list. The quotation markup seems to break it.

Grab (copy) the list into the composing section (above the quoted text), it should still remain in numbered list format. Then at the trailing end of each item that you would like to make a comment press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

1. Rock
   Rock always beats everything
2. Paper
3. Scissors

The same works here at Stack Exchange except one must manually insert spaces pass the indent of the list.

Comment: I tried this, and it worked well -- thanks!